# j_security_check is not available

Tags: java, forms, security, spring, authentication

I am using spring 3.0 and im trying to get my login page working but i get this error

```
The requested resource (/myapp/j_spring_security_check) is not available.
```

I am posting the content of all of my files that have to do with security. Hope it will be enough. If needed i can show more.

Here is my web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

My Login page:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
<style>
.errorblock {
color: #ff0000;
background-color: #ffEEEE;
border: 3px solid #ff0000;
padding: 8px;
margin: 16px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload='document.f.j_username.focus();'>
<h3>Login with Username and Password (Custom Page)</h3>

<c:if test="${not empty error}">
    <div class="errorblock">
        Your login attempt was not successful, try again.<br /> Caused :
        ${sessionScope["SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION"].message}
    </div>
</c:if>

<form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check' />"
    method='POST'>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>User:</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type='password' name='j_password' />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"
                value="submit" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</form>
```

and my security context

```
<beans:bean id="passwordEncoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg value="256" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="saltSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">
    <beans:property name="userPropertyToUse" value="id" />
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="authProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="authProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="personService" />
    <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />
    <beans:property name="saltSource" ref="saltSource" />
    <beans:property name="includeDetailsObject" value="true" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
    <beans:property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
    <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.html" />
</beans:bean>
<http entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" filters="none" />
        <form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/welcome.html"
            authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.html" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
    </http>
```

can someone help me resolve this?

Comment: RESOLVED!

in my jsp i had to add ".html" and redirect started working 

 <form name='f' action="<c:url value='j_spring_security_check**.html**' />"
  method='POST'>

Comment: I believe the reason you had to add .html is because you mapped your spring security filter chain to *.html. That also means that spring security in general will only be applied to *.html requests rather than all requests.  If that is your intention, great, if not, you might want to look at the url-pattern for your springSecurityFilterChain

Answer (score 1):

The .html is definitely required do to the way the filter is set up.  The proper way would be to declare the url-pattern in the web.xml to /*.

If you are going to keep the url-pattern as *.html it might be worthwhile to consider adding the login-processing-url attribute to your form-login element so that if someone does go back and modifies the web.xml everything won't come crashing down due to this quirk.

```
<form-login login-page="/login.html" default-target-url="/welcome.html"
        authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed.html" login-processing-url="j_spring_security_check.html"/>
```